# How to find the all the active users who are currently logged in?

Tags: authentication, session, logout

I am doing some updates on my dev snowflake account and before doing any changes I want to know who are the users who have currently logged in actively in the account. Login_history gives only when they logged in however it does not say at this current moment what are the active users or sessions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the active users from the Snowflake Web UI as an ACCOUNTADMIN, to view the users who are currently logged in.